# Saving dynamically added text input to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dynamic, input

Hey all, using this method [[jQuery append() and remove() element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501181/jquery-append-and-remove-element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501181/jquery-append-and-remove-element) i'm adding text inputs to a document. i'm using this php

```
if($_POST['cp_slider']) 
{ 
  $array=$_POST['cp_slider']; 
  foreach($array as $cp_slider) 
  { 
    if(strlen($cp_slider)>0)
      { 
       echo '<li><input type="text" name="cp_slider[]" value="'.$this->options["theme_slider"].'" /><a href="#" class="remove_project_file" border="2"><img src="images/delete.gif" /></a></li>';
      } 
  } 
}
```

The value was created like this:

```
if ($_POST['to_action'] == 'save') { 
  $this->options["theme_slider"] = $_POST['cp_slider'];
  update_option('artTheme', $this->options);
}
```

But what i see in the value of every input after submitting the form is: Array as a word.

**UPDATE**
I figured it out and it's working fine. The value gets it's real value, i've just changed the foreach line

from this

```
foreach($array as $cp_slider)
```

to this

```
foreach($array as $this->options["theme_slider"])
```

But there is still one problem there. After i submit the form, the data from inputs submits very well. But when i go to another page with in the application and then i'm comming back to the page with this inputs, they are simply not there, they just disappear from the page.

Answer (score 0):

this question seems to vague there are many ways to submit form data so I guess start with a form then choose ajax or maybe you want to look at [jquery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save the data, your jQuery will have to send the request to a PHP script that will take the input and put it into the database somehow.

- User Makes Edits
- Presses 'Save'
- The Save button fires off a jQuery
  AJAX request that sends the
  appropriate data to a PHP script that
  processes/sanitizes it and then puts
  it into the database

If you don't make a call to another script, jQuery will just be updating the HTML seen in the browser and your PHP scripts won't know anything about it.